# OSX maximum window height

Tags: macos, user-interface, window, titlebar, dock

A window can only be a certain height on OSX.  It think this maximum height is: screenheight - menu bar height - title bar height - dock height (only if its visible).

Is there an easy way to get was this value is, or how do you get these values individually?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If You can use `Cocoa` try `visibleFrame` method of `NSScreen` class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame

Answer (score 1):

see NSScreen visibleFrame
And screens 
Register for and handle 
NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification

People use multiple displays, external displays and change their display preferences.

You'll also need to decide what to do about the Dock.

You also need to figure out the height when a window spans multiple displays. 
Or if it should at a maximum size.

You'll want to consider window restoration handling.

You'll do well to consider handling sleep and wake notifications.

Lastly you'll want to test carefully.  This isn't hard but there are a number of dynamics in play that your own setup may not reflect.

One more. Keep in mind that the OS will try to keep a small space for the Dock edge even when the Dock is hiding (left right or bottom) the NSScreen method accounts for this. On Mavericks it seems to be 4 points if I recall correctly. 
You can make your app run with the Dock unavailable while your app is active and front. But doing so by API enforcement also hides the menuBar. If you need to do that, either do full screen or consider increasing the window level a lot. ( that's not as rewarding as it sounds but interesting to explore)

Lastly, this stuff changes sometimes in major OS releases. So expect that you may need to accommodate different OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

> A window can only be a certain height on OS X.

I could not find a reference to the limits of window sizes, but they are definitely less limited than the current screen size.

Windows can stretch over several (vertically) arranged screens or overlap the menubar and the dock.

Comment: Good point. Window levels could be set higher than the dock and menu bar but not terribly practical usually.

Comment: Two monitors, one above the other. You'd want windows that are as high as both monitors.

Comment: no documented maximum, but we can assume it is the extent of a CGFloat for height or width, which is in points in the screen coordinates, and not in pixels